# How do i automatically resize Fonts and Images (complete Website) on window-resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize

How do i automatically resize Fonts and Images (complete Website) on window-resize?
The people will have different screen-res.

css? jquery? html % (didnt work well in chrome)

I need to make a slideshow (presentaion, slides are made with ckeditor)

Comment: Could you possibly use an online tool made for this purpose like [280 Slides](http://280slides.com/Editor/)?

Comment: @Marcel: That site is impressive, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I created a jQuery script to adjust the font-size and img width. This triggers on page load and on window resize based on a percentage of the width of the browser.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Crndp/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    fontSize();
    imgSize();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        fontSize();
        imgSize();
    });

    function fontSize() {
        $ww = $(window).width();
        $fontSize = ($ww / 25) + 'pt';
        $('body').css("font-size", $fontSize);
    }

    function imgSize() {
        $ww = $(window).width();
        $imgSize = ($ww / 5) + 'px';
        $('body img').css("width", $imgSize);    
    }

});
```

You can get more complex with the math on the image resizing based on your needs however this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach almost any event to something like:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('h1').css("fontSize", "32px");
});
```

But if you wanted to make something that was more adaptable you'd have to evaluate the `width` x `height` of `html` element, from that you can derive a reasonable size for the fonts.

There is really no way to generalize it any further, you'd have to write a function on a case by case basis for the elements you'd want to resize.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find this article on **Responsive Web Design** to be very helpful:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

It goes through how to utilise flexible images and how to implement Media Queries (along with other useful things).

The original article was written by **A List Apart** (smashing have added a few things here and there): http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Here is the **finished HTML** of the *responsive demo*: http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-FINAL.html